# Enable Angular's built in directives, like ng-if, to have access to a variable form a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

On the following select field:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="userType" ng-model="userType.field" >
        <option value="">Select</option>
            <option has-permission="can-change-to-admin" ng-if="HOW DO I LINK THIS TO THE DIRECTIVE" value="ADMIN">Admin</option>
            <option has-permission="can-change-to-legal-rep" is-permitted="isPermitted" ng-if="isPermitted" value="LEGAL_REP">Legal Representative</option>
       </select>
```

I have setup a "has-permission" directive which, passed in a string, connects to a service and decides if the user has that permission.

Here is the directive:

```
angular.module('app.common').directive('hasPermission', ['Session', '$state', function (Session, $state) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            hasPermission: '@',
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attributes) {

            var statePermissions = Session.getUserData().statePermissions,
                currentState = $state.current.name;

            scope.isPermitted = true;
            //  HOW CAN I MAKE THE NG-IF FROM THE HTML SEE THIS "ISPERMITTED" VARIABLE?

            if (statePermissions[currentState]) {
                if (statePermissions[currentState].indexOf(scope.hasPermission) === -1) {
                    console.log(statePermissions[currentState])
                    scope.isPermitted = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Now, inside the directive, depending on some settings, I can set a "isPermitted" variable with the values true or false.

**How can I let the ng-if from the select, see the "isPermitted" variable and act according?**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
attributes.ngIf = $scope.isPermitted
```

In this way you can set its true or false value within the directive

**EDIT**: added another possibility

http://jsfiddle.net/fsa58j33/1/

Another possibility is to add dynamically directives to the element:

```
link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
    el.removeAttr("directive");
    el.attr('ng-if', true);
    $compile(el)(scope);
}
```

In this way you don't have to rely on the HTML but on your directive.
It is possible add any directive dynamically as an attribute and then using `$compile(el)(scope)` you make it work.
It is necessary to remove the directive from the element, otherwise it will loop infinitely

Comment: This is a good ideea, but I don't want to add it within the directive since I want to use the isPermitted for other directives, depending on the use case... maybe ngDisable, etc....

Comment: Updated with another option

Answer (score 1):

I wanted this feature myself so built this component. 
It could be expanded somewhat, but covers a basic usecase.

**has-permission.component.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .component('hasPermission', {
      bindings: {
        permission: '<'
      },
      templateUrl: 'app/common/permissions/has-permission/has-permission.html',
      transclude: true,
      controller: Controller
    });

  /** @ngInject */
  function Controller(PermPermissionMap, PermAuthorization) {
    let ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
      let PermissionMap = new PermPermissionMap({
        only: ctrl.permission
      });

      let authorizationResult = PermAuthorization.authorizeByPermissionMap(PermissionMap);

      authorizationResult
        .then(function() {
          ctrl.hasPermission = true;
        })
        .catch(function(rejectedPermission) {
          ctrl.hasPermission = false;
        });
    }

  }


})();
```

**has-permission.html**

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.hasPermission" ng-transclude=""></div>
```

---

**Usage**

```
   <has-permission permission="'panel--read'" class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-app">
        <div class="panel-heading">My Panel</div>
        <div class="panel-content">
          Must have permissions
        </div>
      </div>
    </has-permission>
```